# VendorCredit for QBO

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

What is the IPP API for VendorCredit with QuickBooks Online?

According to the IDS v2 documentation, VendorCredit is available for QBD, but seems to be omitted for QBO.

The IPP QuickBooks v3 slides don't mention VendorCredit at all (see slide 15 http://docs.developer.intuit.com/@api/deki/files/810/QuickBooksAPIv3Webinar-Feb2013.pdf).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VendorCredit is not available for QuickBooks Online through the v2 API.  The lack of VendorCredit in the v3 spec was brought up during the v3 Webinar and noted by the IPP team, but no update regarding VendorCredit has been made.

Comment: Thanks.  I also submitted a support ticket, so hopefully I'll find out something with respect to VendorCredit in v3.